# How to synchronize run configuration with product configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to run an Eclipse product that is configured to use features.

The features added by me are:

```
org.eclipse.e4.rcp
org.eclipse.emf.ecore
org.eclipse.emf.common
```

The product will run after using the run configuration->add required plugins button (the product plugin itself is missing **example:** if the product plugin is called com.company.product I will get a validation error that com.company.product is missing).

If I am using "Launch an Eclipse application" I will get the error "No application id found". This is also obviously reflected in the exported product.

I tried to add the product plugin as dependency but I can't find it. Still the "add required plugins" can add it.

Why is the product plugin itself required and how to add it in the configuration such that the exported product can run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' not sure I really understand the question, but if you are using a feature based product you need to write a feature containing all of your plugins including the one that defines the product using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.product` extension point.

Every plugin that you want to be included in the RCP must be listed in a feature and all the features must be listed in the product file.

I don't know of anything that will synchronize the Run Configuration with the product file.